# Restore Azure SQL Database using T-SQL (create stored procedure)

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I've been asked to write a stored procedure to restore one Azure SQL database from the current copy of a different database.  Up until now I've been achieving this with Powershell, as such:

```
# Restore database from latest geo-redundant backup into existing server 
$GeoBackup = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseGeoBackup -ResourceGroupName "Search_Group1" -ServerName "DataT" -DatabaseName "db_master"

Restore-AzureRmSqlDatabase -FromGeoBackup `
    -ResourceGroupName "Search_Group1" `
    -ServerName "DataT" `
    -TargetDatabaseName "db_search" `
    -ResourceId $GeoBackup.ResourceID `
    -Edition "Standard" `
    -ServiceObjectiveName "S3"
```

So in the above, we take our existing database called `db_master`, and use it's latest backup to create an exact copy called `db_search`.

Is is possible to create a stored procedure that does this?  I was attempting to use the Restore Database UI inside SSMS from which I could then script to T-SQL, but the option to Restore in SSMS is not even present for Azure SQL databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can restore an Azure SQL database using Portal, PowerShell, REST API, ARM template or CLI, but not T-SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.